# PHP "for" loop issue

Tags: php

Simple question:

Why is this:

```
 for($k=1;$k<=10;$k+2) { }
```

giving an infinite loop? When I change $k+2 by $k++, it works fine.

How can I correct it? (I can't change the 10 for an impair number because I need this function to work either with a pair or impair value at that place)

Comment: @Shef $k will always be 1 in this case because $k is not updated

Comment: You are both right, just got up, such an early thought... :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$k+2
```

This won't change `$k`'s value, so it never get's higher than 10. Probably you meant:

```
$k+=2
```

Which will increase `$k` by two each time the expression get's evaluated (at the end of each for-loop).

Answer (score 4):

```
 for($k=1;$k<=10; $k = $k+2) { }
```

or

```
 for($k=1;$k<=10; $k += 2) { }
```

Answer (score 4):

it is infinite loop because $k is not updated, try this instead

```
for($k = 1; $k <= 10; $k = $k + 2) {}
```

or

```
for($k = 1; $k <= 10; $k += 2) {}
```

Reference: [PHP operators](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/operators.php)